# Flickr Api won't recognise string of words?

Tags: javascript, html, api, flickr

Im using the Bing news API to search for a news article based of a word inputed. I then want to display a image for every word in the news article description. For some reason i don't think the Flickr Api is recognising the string.

HTML

```
  <input id="searchterm" />
  <button id="search">search</button>
  <div id="results"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var news;


$("#search").click(function() {
var wordVal = $("#searchterm").val();

var wordSpilt = wordVal.split(" ");




textVal = document.getElementById("searchterm").value;
ajaxCall(textVal);
});


function ajaxCall(textVal) {
$.ajax({
     headers: {
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "9bbe6e6182644abb8ff11df1b6e43035"
    },
    method: "GET",
      url: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?   q=" +
        textVal + "&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safeSearch=Moderate"
 }).done(function(msg) {
    news = msg;
    console.log(news);

    var newsVal = news.value[0].description;



    regex(newsVal);
})
}




function regex(newsVal) {
var newsPun = newsVal.replace(/(~|`|!|@|#|$|%|^|&|\*|\(|\)|{|}|\[|\]|;|:|\"|'|<|,|\.|>|\?|\/|\\|\||-|_|\+|=)/g, "");

runFlickr(newsPun)

}


function runFlickr(newsPun) {

var newSplit = newsPun.split(" ");


for (i = 0; i < newSplit.length; i++) {




    console.log(newSplit[i]);




    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?   jsoncallback=?", {
            tags: $(newSplit[i]),
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        },
        function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).prependTo("#results");
                if (i == 0) return false;
            });
        });

}
};
```

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working pretty well, with the exception of url building. In your question you have used the string:

```
"https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?   q="
```

Just by removeing the empty space I was able to make the snippet run fine.

```js
var news;

$("#search").click(function() {
  textVal = document.getElementById("searchterm").value;
  ajaxCall(textVal);
});

function ajaxCall(textVal) {
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "9bbe6e6182644abb8ff11df1b6e43035"
    },
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?q=" +
      textVal + "&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safeSearch=Moderate"
  }).done(function(msg) {
    news = msg;
    var newsVal = news.value[0].description;
    regex(newsVal);
  })
}

function regex(newsVal) {
  var newsPun = newsVal.replace(/(~|`|!|@|#|$|%|^|&|\*|\(|\)|{|}|\[|\]|;|:|\"|'|<|,|\.|>|\?|\/|\\|\||-|_|\+|=)/g, "");
  runFlickr(newsPun);
}


function runFlickr(newsPun) {
  var newSplit = newsPun.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < newSplit.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?", {
        tags: newSplit[i],
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
          $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).prependTo("#results");
          if (i == 0) return false;
        });
    });

  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchterm" />
<button id="search">search</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

A problem with your code is that `wordVal` and `textVal` are exactly the same thing, the value of `#searchterm`, so please check that out.

**EDIT**
There was a problem in your flicker ajax request syntax, you needed to provide a `.done(function(data))` as a success-callback.

PS: It is not a great idea to get an image for *every* word of the description. Some words have no semantic value (i.e. "a", "the", "some", "here", "there"). You may want to find a way to filter out such words.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the bing news api is working fine, its when i try and link it to the Flickr Image search is plays up? Im trying to make is pull a image for every word in the description

Comment: Can you please show me the Flickr API url where images are queried? An example of a real image search url  would be very helpful.

Comment: The piece of code the calls for the images as at the bottom of the code i previously submitted? Im not 100% sure what you are asking for, please clarify?